# Moto 360 heart rate sensor rarely provides data

Tags: android, wear-os, android-sensors

I managed to get the heart rate sensor and it is working, with some exceptions.
I start the measurement on click, and when there is at least one result with accuracy >= LOW I stop the measurement (by unregistering the listener).
This sequence works 1-2 times, and then it just do not return a value with accuracy >= LOW. I am waiting a few minutes before I give up and close the application. But after opening the app again, most often it works the first 1-2 measurements and then it stops working with the same issue. (but other times it needs a lot of re-launches of the app in order to start giving some results)

Another issue is that if I start the measurement when the watch is not on my wrist/skin but lets say it is floating in the air, then even if I put it on my hand and wait a few minutes it doesn't start giving any valid/accurate value.

Have anybody observed similar behaviour? Is there any specific sequence that needs to be done in order for the sensor to provide more reliable data? Maybe a calibration can be done somehow to make the sensor more sensitive about my skin type or something?

Comment: Are you definitely *not* a vampire?

Comment: @KenWolf I... think so